# Could not initialize class liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator

Tags: java, spring, junit, maven-2, liquibase

Getting this issue when I try to run maven test. Not sure what's causing the issue as these test ran before without issues. My dependencies are being managed by maven

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor379.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.<init>(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:39)
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.getInstance(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:53)
at liquibase.executor.AbstractExecutor.applyVisitors(AbstractExecutor.java:22)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.access$500(JdbcExecutor.java:35)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:284)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:54)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:106)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:96)
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:83)
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:182)
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:148)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:189)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:342)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick fix tested on OSX:

Type in your console:

```
$ hostname -f
```

The output should look somewhat like this:

```
MAC008.local
```

Add this to your hosts file as local host:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Which will look somewhat like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1 MAC008.local
```

Repeat once you change your network.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after switch from Windows to Linux. I found simulair bug https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1943
I configured nss-myhostname and this error was gone.

Comment: where do I find the nss-myhostname config?

Comment: There is a link to http://mytechrantings.blogspot.de/2013/05/how-to-resolve-javanetunknownhostexcept.html in bug description.

Comment: not sure how to fix this as I am on Windows and I've never used Linux on this project.